# Find unique lines

Tags: linux, sorting, unique, uniq

How can I find the unique lines and remove all duplicates from a file?
My input file is

```
1
1
2
3
5
5
7
7
```

I would like the result to be:

```
2
3
```

`sort file | uniq` will not do the job. Will show all values 1 time

Comment: The file must be sorted first. `sort file | uniq -u` will output to console for you.

Comment: I think the reason `sort file | uniq` shows all the values 1 time is because it immediately prints the line it encounters the first time, and for the subsequent encounters, it just skips them.

Answer (score 121):

`uniq` has the option you need:

```
   -u, --unique
          only print unique lines
```

```
$ cat file.txt
1
1
2
3
5
5
7
7
$ uniq -u file.txt
2
3
```

Comment: Make sure you do sort if the entries in the file or not already sorted. sort file.txt | uniq

Comment: see my answer if you don't want to do sort first.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803217/5441945

Answer (score 42):

Use as follows:

```bash
sort < filea | uniq > fileb
```

Comment: This isn't correct, I think you meant: `uniq -u filea > fileb`

Comment: I copy your data and run it and it works: `sort<filea.txt | uniq>fileb.txt`. Maybe you left out the extensions. I am using a Mac OS X. you have to go from `filea.txt` to some other `fileb.txt`

Comment: There is no need for the redirection with `sort` and what's the point of piping to `uniq` when you could just do `sort -u file -o file` what you're doing is removing the duplicate values i.e your `fileb` contains `1,2,3,5,7` the OP wants the unique lines only which is `2,3` and is achieved by `uniq -u file` File extension has nothing to with it, your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 27):

You could also print out the unique value in "file" using the `cat` command by piping to `sort` and `uniq`

```bash
cat file | sort | uniq -u
```

Answer (score 21):

I find this easier.

```bash
sort -u input_filename > output_filename
```

`-u` stands for unique.

Answer (score 19):

While `sort` takes O(n log(n)) time, I prefer using

```bash
awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

---

`awk '!seen[$0]++'` is an abbreviation for `awk '!seen[$0]++ {print}'`, print line(=$0) if `seen[$0]` is not zero.
It take more space but only O(n) time.

Answer (score 14):

you can use:

```bash
sort data.txt| uniq -u
```

this sort data and filter by unique values

Answer (score 11):

uniq -u has been driving me crazy because it did not work.

So instead of that, if you have python (most Linux distros and servers already have it):

## Assuming you have the data file in notUnique.txt

```
#Python
#Assuming file has data on different lines
#Otherwise fix split() accordingly.

uniqueData = []
fileData = open('notUnique.txt').read().split('\n')

for i in fileData:
  if i.strip()!='':
    uniqueData.append(i)

print uniqueData

###Another option (less keystrokes):
set(open('notUnique.txt').read().split('\n'))
```

## Note that due to empty lines, the final set may contain '' or only-space strings. You can remove that later. Or just get away with copying from the terminal ;)

#

Just FYI, From the uniq Man page:

"Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.  You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'.  Also, comparisons honor the rules specified by 'LC_COLLATE'."

One of the correct ways, to invoke with:
#
sort nonUnique.txt | uniq

### Example run:

```
$ cat x
3
1
2
2
2
3
1
3

$ uniq x
3
1
2
3
1
3

$ uniq -u x
3
1
3
1
3

$ sort x | uniq
1
2
3
```

## Spaces might be printed, so be prepared!

Comment: This is overkilling.

Answer (score 5):

```bash
uniq -u < file
```

will do the job.

Comment: No need for the redirection.

Comment: Yea I know. Did it habitually

Answer (score 3):

`uniq` should do fine if you're file is/can be sorted, if you can't sort the file for some reason you can use `awk`:

```bash
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]<2)print i}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```bash
sort -d "file name" | uniq -u
```

this worked for me for a similar one. Use this if it is not arranged.
You can remove sort if it is arranged

Answer (score 1):

Short, foolproof way:

```bash
sort -u file
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the first i tried

```
skilla:~# uniq -u all.sorted  

76679787
76679787 
76794979
76794979 
76869286
76869286 
......
```

After doing a cat -e all.sorted

```
skilla:~# cat -e all.sorted 
$
76679787$
76679787 $
76701427$
76701427$
76794979$
76794979 $
76869286$
76869286 $
```

Every second line has a trailing space :(
After removing all trailing spaces it worked!

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting and then using `uniq`, you could also just use `sort -u`. From `sort --help`:

```
  -u, --unique              with -c, check for strict ordering;
                            without -c, output only the first of an equal run
```