# How to print only the unique lines in BASH?

Tags: bash, uniq

How can I print only those lines that appear exactly once in a file? E.g., given this file:

```
mountain
forest
mountain
eagle
```

The output would be this, because the line `mountain` appears twice:

```
forest
eagle
```

- The lines can be sorted, if necessary.

Comment: I think you can use dictionary. You can have a look on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find unique lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778273/find-unique-lines)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{!seen[$0]++};END{for(i in seen) if(seen[i]==1)print i}' file
eagle
forest
```

Comment: No need of going so complex. simple `uniq` command will do the job as well.

Comment: 1. Its not complex and 2. It avoids expensive `sort` for larger files.

Comment: @anubhava Nice awk. +1. But for it _is_ really simpler to use `uniq`. And keeping in the memory larger files - who knows - what is more expensive. Swapping or sorting. :)

Comment: @anubhava just tested on 300k lines. This `awk` solution is 8 times faster than `sort|uniq`.

Comment: @jm666: Thanks so much for running the test and verifying that awk command is faster than `sort|uniq`.

Comment: Since we are iterating, we can quickly check and print only those which is seen just once. `awk '{!seen[$0]++};END{for(i in seen) if(seen[i]==1)print i}' file` but +1 none the less.

Comment: Yes sure that can also be done, I just chose delete to free up some memory not sure how much will that help :)

Comment: @anubhava Thats a valid point, but as the solution is right now, it will probably get confused when the number of dups are in odd numbers. For example, if you add another `mountain` row, it will print it as well.

Comment: @jaypal: Ah that's very important point. I updated as you suggested, many thanks!

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the edit and you're always welcome. `:)`

Comment: @jm666 I tried with my `.xsession-errors.old` file (129315 lines), and the `sort | uniq` solution is 5 times _faster_ than this `awk` solution...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf `sort` also has added benefit of writing the cache to disk if memory is not available. `awk` does not have that benefit.

Comment: I created a `803200 lines` text file. My awk command took: `1.946s` whereas `sort|uniq` took `3.188s` on my OSX.

Comment: my OS X is probably slow on IO, because i did: `gsort -uR /usr/share/dict/* > words.txt` (the gsort is the GNU version of sort - for getting randomly ordered file) - got 312123 lines. And tested both commands: `time sort words.txt | uniq -u >/dev/null` (got: 8.4 secs) and `time awk .... words.txt >/dev/null` got: 1.3 secs. So, for me (repeated few times) the awk is (nearly) 8 times faster than sort.

Answer (score 124):

Use `sort` and `uniq`:

```
sort inputfile | uniq -u
```

The `-u` option would cause `uniq` to print only unique lines.  Quoting from `man uniq`:

```
   -u, --unique
          only print unique lines
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
eagle
forest
```

**Obs:** Remember to `sort` before `uniq -u` because `uniq` operates on *adjacent* lines. So what `uniq -u` actually does is to print lines that don't have identical neighbor lines, but that doesn't mean they are really unique. When you `sort`, all the identical lines get grouped together and only the lines that are *really* unique in the file will remain after `uniq -u`.

Comment: @jordan Don't know.  Somebody didn't like it, perhaps.

Comment: @anubhava Did you try it?

Comment: Apologies I missed `-u` in copy/paste.

Comment: I like simple answer. A +1 for that simplicity.

Answer (score 10):

You almost had the answer in your question:

`sort filename | uniq -u`