# List folder contents and only show unique value

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal, grep

Is there a way to use the 'ls' command then then pipe the output to only show the unique item?

Here is the example:

```
ls /dev/disk/by-id


ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_S2AFE0JP
ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_W2AEDMQK
ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_W2AEDMQK-part1
ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_W2AEDMQK-part2
ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_W2AEDMQK-part3
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EEV65804
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EEV65804-part1
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EEV65804-part9
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EKK60289
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EKK60289-part1
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EKK60289-part9
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2ET092491
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2ET092491-part1
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2ET092491-part9
ata-WDC_WD5003AZEX-00MK2A0_WD-WCC3F2HAD1XC
ata-WDC_WD5003AZEX-00MK2A0_WD-WCC3F2HAD1XC-part1
ata-WDC_WD5003AZEX-00MK2A0_WD-WCC3F2HAD1XC-part9
```

As you can see in the output all but one of the items has the serial number and a -part# to it, but the serial ontop:

> 'ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_S2AFE0JP'

Does not. What I am trying to do is get the output to only show me the resits that do not have any other duplicate serial entries.The out out would be just the unique serial number.

```
ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_S2AFE0JP
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is expected output and please include your attempt

Comment: I added the expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print only the unique lines in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740545/how-to-print-only-the-unique-lines-in-bash)

Comment: btw: why this is not matching your parameters? ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_W2AEDMQK

Comment: You can collect names in an array using a glob like `files=( /dev/disk/by-id/* )`. You can modify the contents of an array using parameter expansion, like `serials=( "${files[@]#ata-}" ) serials=( "${files[@]%-part*}" )`. You can output such an array using `printf '%s\n' "${serials[@]}"`. You can make a list unique using `sort -u`.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: There are other lines in this output that do not have `part` in them. What **precisely**  is different about the first line vs the others?

Comment: What for example is the difference between `ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_S2AFE0JP` and 
`ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_W2AEDMQK`?

Comment: @dawg the different is that ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_W2AEDMQK, has the -part# after it, I am trying to only output any serual that does not have the part#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these entries don't contain newlines, you may use:

```
printf '%s\n' /dev/disk/by-id/* |
awk '!/-part[0-9]*$/{arr[$0]; next} { sub(/-[^-]+$/, ""); delete arr[$0] } 
END { for (i in arr) print i }'
```

```
ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_S2AFE0JP
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep with a regular expression : ls | grep -Ev  'part.*$'

```
$ ls test
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EEV65804        ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EEV65804-part9  ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2ET092491-part1
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EEV65804-part1  ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2ET092491        ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2ET092491-part9
$ ls test | grep -Ev 'part.*$'
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EEV65804
ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2ET092491
```

Comment: Getting this error: grep: invalid option -- 'p'

Comment: I fixed the answer as the "-" was considered as an option.

Comment: Not working, I still get the serial numbers, (serial)- - part#

Comment: Don't forget the dot right before the *. I just fixed it.

Comment: It is close, but also if the serial had an -part# associated with it, to eliminate that as well from the output

Comment: Generally [don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @tripleee, if not ls,then what command to output the contents?

Comment: Read the link; that's why I provided it.